# Equivalent of Azure tools on Windows Server Bus (On Premises)

Tags: azureservicebus, bus

I installed Windows Service Bus 1.0 for Windows.

This page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brunoterkaly/2014/08/07/learn-how-to-create-a-queue-place-and-read-a-message-using-azure-service-bus-queues-in-5-minutes/
shows a web based tool to administer the BUS, such as creating new queues.

Does such a thing exist on the "on-premises" version? Or do you have to everything in code?  I'm running on Windows 10 Home (at the moment), and don't have IIS.  If I had IIS, would it have installed those tools?  I didn't see IIS on the pre-reqs list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193017.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Does such a thing exist on the "on-premises" version? Or do you have to everything in code? I'm running on Windows 10 Home (at the moment), and don't have IIS. If I had IIS, would it have installed those tools?

I assumed that you could leverage Service Bus 1.1 for Windows Server which could integrate with Windows Azure Pack to manage your resources and services on-premises.

As the [release notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282143.aspx) for Service Bus 1.1 mentioned that it supports management portal with the [Windows Azure Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-azure-pack) integration as follows:

> **Windows Azure Pack for Windows Server is a collection of Azure technologies, available to Microsoft customers at no additional cost for installation into your data center**. It runs on top of Windows Server 2012 R2 and System Center 2012 R2 and, through the use of the Azure technologies, enables you to offer a rich, self-service, multi-tenant cloud, consistent with the public Azure management experience.

The following are highlights of the new features available with the Windows Azure Pack integration:

> - **Service Bus tenant portal**: Windows Azure Pack offers a rich tenant portal to manage IT resources and services. Messaging with Service Bus is one of the supported services, as well as Virtual Machines, Web sites, SQL databases, and more. The Windows Azure Pack portal enables a subscription-based user experience similar to the one found in Azure.
> - **Service Bus admin experience**: Windows Azure Pack offers an administrator experience that enables you to deploy, manage and monitor resources and services.
> - **Azure PowerShell cmdlets**: Windows Azure Pack supports Azure PowerShell management for IT services, including Service Bus.

I assumed that you could follow the steps below to build your management protal on-premises:

- Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441399.aspx) for installing Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1
- Install and configure the Windows Azure Pack admin site, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn296432.aspx) for deploying Windows Azure Pack for Windows Server.
- Create a [New Service Bus Farm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441401.aspx). Note if you want the Service Bus farm to be managed in the Windows Azure Pack portal, click **Manage this farm with the Service Bus Management Portal** before you apply the listed options.
- Connect to your Windows Pack management site to enable administrators to use Service Bus for Windows Server, you could refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440945.aspx).

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441425.aspx) about configuring Service Bus for Windows Server using Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Long answer, but bottom line, I think you were saying: Go install "Windows Portal API Pack Portal and API Express" from the "Web Platform Installer". I did that, but looks like I'm going to need IIS to get full functionality.

Comment: And actually, I had installed "Service Bus 1.0" as mentioned very specifically in my question.  I now see that there is also a "Windows Azure Pack Service Bus 1.1".  Does that change the answer?

Comment: Or was my question totally off.  Perhaps the question should have been "\Are there GUI tools for the "Service Bus 1.0"?

Comment: Yes, I mean that you could leverage Windows Service Bus 1.1 with Windows Pack Portal to manage your Windows Service Bus On Premises. As I known, there is no GUI tools for Windows Service Bus 1.0.